# Rails: Where clause doesn't work in any condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, rails-activerecord, crud

I'm about to lose my mind due to a simple Rails **where** query. I simply cannot understand why it does work like 10 lines ago and does not after it. I could not figure out what might be causing the problem

```
@userID = Token.where(:tokenCode => @tokenReceived)
  #@init.tokenCode=@tokenReceived+"1" #randomize algorithm required!
  @init.tokenCode=@codeGenerated=generate_activation_code()
  if @userID.nil?
    @newToken=Token.new
    @newToken.tokenCode=@codeGenerated
  else
    @tokenToAdd = "12"
    @newToken=Token.where(:userID => "1")
    #if @newToken.nil?
      @newToken.tokenCode="12"
    #end
  end
  #@newToken.save  
  @init.save
```

When I make a successful JSON request to 'http://localhost:3000/inits.json' it gives me a page with tons of erros but I think the main error among those are:

```
<h1>
  NoMethodError
    in InitsController#create
</h1>
<pre>undefined method `tokenCode=&#x27; for #&lt;ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fc43cb40b88&gt;</pre>
```

What could be the reason? Am I writing the where clause all wrong?

**Edit:** When I activate the if clause it works. I simply believe the @newToken object is null, however it is almost impossible for me to detect why. There is a data in my Token table with **userID** 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
 @newToken=Token.where(:userID => "1")
```

You get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but you expect an object. So simply replace it with:

```
 @newToken=Token.where(:userID => "1").first
```

Comment: Thanks for your incredibly great answer! You saved my life.